# WindowsContext: OleInitialize() failed: "COM error 0x80010106 RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE (Unknown error 0x0ffffffff80010106)"

Tags: python, pyqt5, pywinauto

I'm programming in python 3.4.4 (32 bits), in windows 8. I'm running an app with PyQt5, the app was working well, but since i installed pywinauto 0.6.4 to set the focus on other app with:

```
other_app = pywinauto.Application().connect(process=int(code))
other_app.top_window().set_focus()
```

if i run `My_app = QApplication(sys.argv)`, in console appears the next warning message, with no other information:

```
QWindowsContext: OleInitialize() failed:  "COM error 0x80010106 RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE (Unknown error 0x0ffffffff80010106)"
SetProcessDpiAwareness failed: "COM error 0x80070005  (Unknown error 0x0ffffffff80070005)"
```

I suspect that's because there is a conflict between the `pywinauto` and the `PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication` modules. After the "warning" the program runs good, but i still don't now how to fix it.

This is the Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import pywinauto
import sys


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you. At the end of the question is the Minimal Complete and Verifiable example.

Comment: I get the very same error when using `matplotlib.pyplot` on Win8.1 and Py3.7.

Answer (score 8):

According to this [post](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/472) a workaround is to use `sys.coinit_flags = 2` and warning module.

```
import sys
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore", UserWarning)
sys.coinit_flags = 2
import pywinauto
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QMainWindow()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: In my case, the program did also crash with no apparent reason, but this fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: I am facing the similar issue but with pyside2 lib. and above solution doesn't work with my code. :(

Comment: @SagarMehta Did you manage to find a solution??

Comment: Nope, I was in time crunch so switched to tkinter to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue working with PySide2. In my case, the import order made the difference. Namely, I was using

```
import clr
```

which must be placed **after**

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to import in this way:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
...
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QMainWindow()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

This works for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please explain your answer, why does it solve the problem and how.